# How can i make a nested if trigger work to auto analyze my logs?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a database where I can store logs and let and after insert trigger analyze them for me.

But for some reason, it is not working and MySql does not help with its error messages.

EDIT: What this trigger is supposed to do is to compare the New log being inserted to the logs stored in test_logs and if they are related generate a new log to the table sorted_logs.

For example: "IF NEW.BlockId = test_logs.BlockId" This comparison purpose is to compare the BlockId from the new entry inserted in table test_logs to the row of the same table that is being iterated over by "For each row".

EDIT2: [test_logs table content example](https://prnt.sc/1t8v1x4) This table hold a logId, a BlockId witch identifies the item being loged, LocalPeer the identifier of the user that sent said item, RemotePeer the identifier of the user who received said item, the time the item was send/received/requested and a boolean that identifies whether the item transmission was duplicate or not

Thanks in advance for all the help you can give me.

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `sorted_logs`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `sorted_logs` (
  `LogID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Test_LogID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `BlockId` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `Sender` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `Receiver` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `RequestDelay` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BlockDelay` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BlockDelivered` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Duplicate` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`LogID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `sorted_logs`
--

LOCK TABLES `sorted_logs` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `sorted_logs` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `sorted_logs` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `test_logs`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test_logs`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `test_logs` (
  `LogID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `BlockId` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `LocalPeer` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `RemotePeer` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `SentAt` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `ReceivedAt` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `BlockRequestedAt` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Duplicate` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`LogID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `test_logs`
--

LOCK TABLES `sorted_logs` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `sorted_logs` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `sorted_logs` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Trigger structure for table `test_logs`
--

DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `analize_logs`;
Create trigger `analize_logs` after insert on test_logs 
    For each row 
    Begin
        IF NEW.BlockId = test_logs.BlockId AND New.SentAt <> 0 AND test_logs.BlockRequestedAt <> 0 AND New.RemotePeer = test_logs.LocalPeer AND New.LocalPeer = test_logs.RemotePeer Then 
            SET @requestdelay := TIMESTAMPDIFF(MICROSECOND, test_logs.BlockRequestedAt, New.SentAt);
            Insert into sorted_logs (Test_LogID, BlockId, Sender, Receiver, RequestDelay, BlockDelivered, Duplicate) values (New.LogID, New.BlockId, New.LocalPeer, New.RemotePeer, @requestdelay, 0, New.Duplicate);
        END IF;
        IF New.BlockId = test_logs.BlockId AND New.LocalPeer = test_logs.RemotePeer AND New.RemotePeer = test_logs.LocalPeer AND New.ReceivedAt <> 0 AND test_logs.SentAt <> 0 Then 
            If (Select count(sorted_logs.BlockId) from sorted_logs where sorted_logs.BlockId = New.BlockId and sorted_logs.Test_LogID = test_logs.LogID) <> 0 then 
                SET @blockdelay := TIMESTAMPDIFF(MICROSECOND, New.ReceivedAt, test_logs.SentAt);
                Update sorted_logs set sorted_logs.BlockDelay = @blockdelay, sorted_logs.Sender = New.LocalPeer, sorted_logs.Receiver = New.RemotePeer, sorted_logs.BlockDelivered = 1, sorted_logs.Duplicate = New.Duplicate where sorted_logs.BlockId = New.BlockId and sorted_logs.Test_LogID = LogID;
            Else
                SET @blockdelay := TIMESTAMPDIFF(MICROSECOND, tNew.ReceivedAt, New.SentAt);
                Insert into sorted_logs (Test_LogID, BlockId, Sender, Receiver, BlockDelay, BlockDelivered, Duplicate) values (New.LogID, New.BlockId, New.LocalPeer, New.RemotePeer, @blockdelay, 1, New.Duplicate);
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END; //
DELIMITER ; 

LOCK TABLES `test_logs` WRITE;
```

Comment: It is unclear what your trigger is supposed to do. MySQL has the same problem, but appearently cannot tell that to you. But you are in luck: we can! For example, `IF NEW.BlockId = test_logs.BlockId` compares something to somehting, but neither we nor MySQL knows to what. Now you come in to play: tell us what that is supposed to do. Then we can tell you how to tell MySQL what you want to do.

Comment: *`IF NEW.BlockId = test_logs.BlockId AND`* You cannot refer to `test_logs` columns in the condition because the condition have no rows source (like FROM clause in the query).

Comment: Explain in details the logic of new row analyzing - maybe we'll help you to create correct trigger code.

Comment: @Akina and Solarflare thanks for your comments, I tried to give a little bit more context on how the trigger is supposed to work

Comment: Provide sample tables content (as INSERT INTO, 3-5 rows), 2-3 INSERT queries (some insert "related" data, some - not related) and desired final tables state with detailed explanations referred to definite values..

Comment: @MatiasCorreia provide the table structure and the queries that you tried.